# Does the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{2}e^{\frac{-n^{3}}{3}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^{2}e^{\frac{-n^{3}}{3}}$$ converge or diverge?

I have attempted using the alternating series test, but couldn't find a useful function to use as $b_n$ and no other tests I know seem to be useful in coming to the conclusion of whether it is convergent or divergent.

Comment: Is the power of the( -1 ) 2?

Comment: oops that is supposed to be n

Comment: So you should show that $f(n)=n^2*e^\frac{-n^3}{3}$ is a deacreasing function for large enough $n$

Comment: I have no theorem or proof to do that with. For certain functions it is not possible to know that is always applicable because it is like multiplying 0 by infinity.

Comment: Yes you can treat the function as a function on the reals and take the derivative of it. The natural numbers are a subset of the reals

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivial. $n^2 e^{-n^3}$ has a more-than-exponential decay hence the given series is clearly absolutely convergent.

Comment: That's not trivial to a student learning it for the first time.  :(

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It may be "trivial" to you but to the level of mathematics I have done this is different.

Comment: I understand your points but please take mine too into consideration: do we really want MSE to be flooded by Calc-1 almost trivial questions? I am fine with a reasonable amount of them to occupy the main page, but nowadays they are becoming way too many. In my humble opinion of course, and as an active member of MSE I have the power to express it through votes. I am fine with others disagreeing with me, too.

Comment: @goldenlinx Surely you have learned that exponential decay overcomes any power of $n?$

Comment: @zhw. No, nothing of the sort was included in my curriculum.

Comment: @goldenlinx Really? You never learned that $n/e^n \to 0?$

Comment: @zhw. Nope, I just learnt that now from your comment. They tell us it's infinity/infinity so we need to approach it in a different manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series converges absolutely. This is because we have $$0 \leq \exp\left(-\frac{n^3}{3}\right) \leq \frac{1}{1 + \frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{n^6}{18}}$$

by considering the Taylor expansion  and hence

$$0 \leq n^2\exp\left(-\frac{n^3}{3}\right) \leq \frac{n^2}{1 + \frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{n^6}{18}} \leq 18n^{-4}$$

and $$\sum 18n^{-4}$$ converges by the integral test.

More intuitively, just keep in mind that exponentials of the form $a^{-x}$ for $a>1$ decay faster than any rational function.

If you want to use the alternating series test to merely establish conditional convergence, you can use L'hopital to show $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2e^{-\frac{x^3}{3}} = 0$

Comment: Thank you I see how to solve the question much more clearly now.

Answer (score 3):

Letting $a_n = (-1)^n n^2 e^{-\frac{n^3}{3}}$, we have
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = - \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2} e^{-\frac{(n+1)^3}{3}}e^{\frac{n^3}{3}} = -\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 e^{-\frac{3n^2+3n+1}{3}}$$

Then as $n \to \infty$, note $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \to 1$ and since $n^2+n+\frac{1}{3} \to \infty$, the exponential tends to zero so
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = 0 < 1$$
so the series converges by the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

$|a_n|=|(-1)^nn^2e^{-\frac {n^3}{3}}|=\left(n^2e^{-\frac {n^3}{6}}\right)e^{-\frac {n^3}{6}}\le e^{-\frac {n^3}{6}}\le e^{-n}\quad$ for $n$ large enough.

- The first inequality is because any polynom is small in regard to any exponential (their product is going to zero), so for $n\gg 1$ large enough, $n^2e^{-\frac {n^3}{6}}<1$.
- The second one is because $e^{-x}$ is decreasing, so since $\frac {n^3}6>n$, once again for $n\gg 1$ large enough, we have $e^{-\frac {n^3}{6}}\le e^{-n}$

So for $n$ large enough we have $|a_n|<e^{-n}$ which is a term of a convergent geometric serie (of reason $0<\frac 1e<1$), so the original serie is absolutely convergent (because positive terms makes the partial sum increasing and it is bounded by the sum of the other serie, so it has a limit).

Remember that if you can get a straightforward result by rough majorations like in this case, always go for it before invoking more powerful tools. Advanced tools will give you more precise estimations, but it's good to come back to the basics, analysis is the art of minoration and majoration.

Answer (score 0):

The series is absolutely convergent. Apply the quotient criterion.